# Mercurial Issue when updating

Tags: python, mercurial

I am trying to do a terminal update and I keep getting this error, no matter what.

/Volumes/www/working/.hg/wlock.break
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py:157: DeprecationWarning: use lock.release instead of del lock
  return -1

Any ideas as to what this is?

Out of date versions?

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.2 thanks

Comment: it's a warning, not an error.

Comment: I've tried Tortuouhg on windows and I keep getting this error, I tried the macmerial and hg80, so not sure why I keep getting it when I modify 1 single file or try to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of mercurial are you running?  It looks like a lot of these (harmless warning) messages have been cleaned up according to the [mercurial bug tracker](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org).

Comment: It was my SMB share, using a different system solved the issue